# rails console get all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have a very simple question about rails console, if I want to get a single account I do this:
y Account.find_by_zipcode("XXXXX")

This returns me only one account, what if I want to get all the accounts which have that zipcode. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Account.find_all_by_zipcode('XXXXX')`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Account.where(:zipcode => "XXXXX")
```

This returns an array of Account objects.

Comment: No it doesn't. 

Answer (score 1):

```
Account.where(zipcode: "XXXXX")
```

is the way to go. "find_all" is depreciated in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

`Account.where(:zipcode => 'XXXXX')` will give you what you want.